# Android sql query using WHERE clause

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I have a question regarding how to incorporate a WHERE clause when querying a sql database in Android. My goal is to return specific records from my database `where the date picked by a datepicker matches the date stored`.

Here is my code:

```
private static String datePickerDate = "3/29/2011";
private static String[] FROM = { _ID, NAME, PRICE, DATE, TIME };
private static String ORDER_BY = TIME + " DESC ";
private static String WHERE = DATE + "is like " + datePickerDate;
private Cursor getEvents(){
    // Perform a managed Query. The Activity will handle closing
    // and re-querying the cursor when needed
    SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}
```

My questions are thus: 
Where does my "WHERE" statement go?

And is my "WHERE" statement correct?

The documentation I found for db.query doesn't specify if a "WHERE" clause can be used, it just specifies that a "HAVING" clause is possible, but I don't quite think that's what I'm wanting.

```
 db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)
```

Comment: you might want to change `"is like "` to `" is like "` (notice the space before `is`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `selection` represents your WHERE clause.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> selection A filter declaring which
>   rows to return, formatted as an SQL
>   WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE
>   itself). Passing null will return all
>   rows for the given table.

So you can try this (untested):

```
private static String WHERE = "DATE like ?";
db.query(table, columns, WHERE , new String[] { datePickerDate }, groupBy, having, orderBy)
```

Comment: @ccheneson I am also facing similar issue. Here is my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806818/how-to-use-query-for-multiple-selection-argument-using-one-selection-column

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the WHERE clause, I would suggest using the raw query function in the SQLiteDatabase class, shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

This way, you can have the raw query typed out (or in segments) as if you were doing it naturally with SQL.

**EDIT:**  On a side note, the "selection" parameter of the query() function corresponds to the WHERE clause, as noted [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: `rawQuery()` should only be used when its really necessary. `query()` should always be used for normal select queries.

Comment: out of curiosity, why?  I use a lot of raw queries in my apps and it makes it personally easier for me.  I'm not doubting, I'm just curious.

Comment: I started writing about performance and stuff like that but after diving into the source (looked at 2.3.1 r1) I must say, they use the same methods at the end (despite the fact of building a SQL statement first, when `query()` is used), so finally... I must admit: if you know SQL, use `rawQuery()`... thanks for being curious, you were right :)

Comment: thanks for going through the effort!  That gives me a little peace of mind.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I had pondered using rawQuery() but decided against it, although it is incredibly comforting to know that the two boil down to the same.

Answer (score 0):

About where you're "WHERE" goes - look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

And regarding the second part, I think you miss the qouts before and after the value, it should be `.. like '3/29/2011'` and not `.. is like 3/29/2011`