# How to use query for multiple selection argument using one selection column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

Here is my query :

```
// Table Name : Question
  Cursor cursor = db.query("QUESTION", new String[] { "TEXT", "OPTION_A",
    "OPTION_B", "OPTION_C", "OPTION_D", "OPTION_E",
    "RIGHT_ANSWER" },
    "SUBJECT=?", new String[] { "Ingles", "Historia" }, null,null,
    null);
```

I can have multiple subjects, right now i am having only two subjects(Ingles,Historia)

How to sort data by subjects using query??

I am getting bind or out of range error. I know error is somewhere in **where** clause , but not able to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer.

1) To sort the data, need to enter column name in last argument

2) When multiple selection condition is available in one column use `IN Operator`.

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query("QUESTION", new String[] { "TEXT", "OPTION_A",
            "OPTION_B", "OPTION_C", "OPTION_D", "OPTION_E",
            "RIGHT_ANSWER" },
            "SUBJECT IN(?,?)", new String[] { "Ingles", "Historia" }, null,null,
            "SUBJECT");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because number of "?" in where and array length in arguments mismatch. You can put condition like this 
1) Using two conditions in where 
`Cursor cursor = db.query("QUESTION", new String[] { "TEXT", "OPTION_A", "OPTION_B", "OPTION_C", "OPTION_D", "OPTION_E", "RIGHT_ANSWER" }, "SUBJECT1=? AND SUBJECT2=? ", new String[] { "Ingles", "Historia" }, null,null, "SUBJECT");`
2) Using IN condition 
`Cursor cursor = db.query("QUESTION", new String[] { "TEXT", "OPTION_A", "OPTION_B", "OPTION_C", "OPTION_D", "OPTION_E", "RIGHT_ANSWER" }, "SUBJECT IN(?)", new String[] { "Ingles,Historia" }, null,null, "SUBJECT");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my selection argument is not fixed,it can be 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. How to make the query run dynamically??

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal You can use StringBuilder and append all values separated by "," like current_ids.append(id).append(","); and pass this variable to query.